# Angularjs - uib-datepicker in an table

Tags: angularjs, datepicker

I am trying to display an uib-datepicker in a table.

```
<table ng-table="tableParamsReglement"  class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="dynamic-table" >
    <tr ng-repeat="activite in $data"  >
        <td  class="text-center" data-title="'Date fin astreinte'" >
            <div class="input-group">
                <input id="field_dateReglementEffectifClient" type="text" class="form-control" name="dateReglementEffectifClient" uib-datepicker-popup="{{vm.formatDate}}" ng-model="activite.dateReglementEffectifClient"
                       is-open="vm.datePickerOpenStatus.dateReglementEffectifClient" />
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="vm.openCalendar('dateReglementEffectifClient')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
                </span>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Controller :

```
vm.datePickerOpenStatus = {};
vm.datePickerOpenStatus.dateReglementEffectifClient = false;

vm.openCalendar = function(date) {
    vm.datePickerOpenStatus[date] = true;
};
```

When I click on the calendar button multiple calendars show. And I when I choose a date, it's applied on the last element of my table.

I don't know what I am doing wrong here.

[image]

Comment: You are giving the same ID to all input fields (`<input id="field_dateReglementEffectifClient" ...>`). Could you try giving different ids to them?

Comment: I have tried without Id, it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

Solved with :

```
<td  class="text-center" data-title="'Date fin astreinte'" >
    <div class="input-group">
        <input  type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="{{vm.formatDate}}" ng-model="activite.dateReglementEffectifClient"
               is-open="activite.isOpen" />
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="vm.openCalendar($event, activite)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
        </span>
    </div>
</td>

vm.openCalendar = function($event, activite) {
    $event.preventDefault();
    $event.stopPropagation();

    activite.isOpen = true;
};
```